# How can I simplify then solve this wordy age problem?

Tags: word-problem

About a month ago, my high school had its first math team competition. In one of the events (Fr/So 8-person), the following question was asked:

> "All ages in this problem are in whole number of years. Tom is now 3 times as old as Kay was when Tom was 4 times as old as Kay had been when Kay was 1/2 as old as Kay is now. If the sum of their present ages is 26 years, find the number of years in Tom's age now.

What would be a strategy that I could use to simplify it down into easier to understand equations, and then to solve it?

Comment: You start by defining variables, $T$ for Tom's age now and $K$ for Katy's age now.  The last sentence gives $T+K=26$.  You have to read the sentence before carefully to get an equation out of it.  Alternatively, you know that $T$ is a multiple of $3$.  There are not many of those below $26$, so you can just try them by plugging in.

Comment: The strategy is, 1) identify the unknowns, 2) give them names, 3) write down equations relating the unknowns, 4) solve those equations.

Comment: $D =$ current day. $T+K = 26$. At time $D_1,$ Kay was $K/2$ years old, so $D - K/2 = D_1$.  At $D_2$, Tom was $4 \times K/2 = 2K$, so $D_2 = D - (T - 2K).$  And on, and on, ...

Comment: The key to simplifying this problem is in the realization that there is a constant difference in the two ages: $T-K=C$ This should lead you to $T=3(2K-C)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem lies in this sentence:

> Tom is now 3 times as old as Kay was when Tom was 4 times as old as Kay had been when Kay was 1/2 as old as Kay is now.

Let Tom be $X$ years old and Kay be $Y$ years old. Break down from back to front:

1. when Kay was 1/2 as old as Kay is now
   -> when Kay was $\frac Y2$ years old
   -> $\frac Y2$ years ago.
2. when Tom was 4 times as old as Kay had been *when Kay was 1/2 as old as Kay is now*.
   -> when Tom was 4 times as old as Kay had been $\frac Y2$ years ago.
   -> when Tom was $4 \cdot \frac Y2$ years old
   -> $X-2Y$ years ago
3. Tom is now 3 times as old as Kay was *when Tom was 4 times as old as Kay had been when Kay was 1/2 as old as Kay is now*.
   -> Tom is now 3 times as old as Kay was $X-2Y$ years ago
   -> $X = 3\cdot[Y-(X-2Y)]$
   -> $4X=9Y$